# Webbrowser control in asp.net?

Tags: asp.net, browser

I need to do this: 
1) enter a certain website using my clients usernames and pass- they are aware of that offcourse :) 
2) navigate inside, a matter of 6 steps 
3) download a .csv file from the site 
It's a water meter reading site, and I want to update my DB automaticly every hour.

Using WebBrowser in c#, it works great. **But**, I need it to be on a server and run it all the time for the info to be up to date. 
Webservices aren't valid because the reading site has nothing to do with me (3rd side company etc.).
So basically, what I need is to mimic the webbrowser control. what I found unthe codeproject didn't helped me.
I'm checking if CGI can do the trick, but perhaps I'm offtrack here.
thanks for your help!

Comment: Using the WebBrowser control is going to be heavy; you can't just visit the csv link passing the credentials using [`HttpWebRequest`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.aspx)?

Comment: Hey, no. it's not a permenant link, it's a result of a form (choosing the type of reading etc.)

Comment: It may not be as "simple", but anything you need performed can be done using that object (down to submitting form data, retrieving a previous page, etc.)

Comment: I would also suggest the [HttpWebRequest class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.aspx). You could start another thread from the ASP.NET request that does point 2 and 3. Or you simply update the database with the value the user entered and a WindowsService is used that reads that value.

Comment: I am not completely sure if  i have understood your needs correctly but would it work to use WATIN and write a UI Test for for the above 3 steps. All you then need to implement is a windows service which checks for existence of the file in a predefined location, loads it,  and updates the db from the contents.

Comment: HttpWebRequest class looks like a great lid, I'll check it. Thank you all, I'll update!

Answer (score 1):

You can use the HttpRequest/Response objects in the System.Net namespace. They don't mimic the web control but they do allow you to make the requests you want.

Comment: Thanks, I'm trying to use this classes, but can't find anywhere an example to how httprequest actually should look like. I'm using Fiddler2, but I can't figure out of it the syntax. Help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks.